# How can I list rows meeting a criteria and limit the amount of rows by a sum of the list?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a scheduling assistant within Google Sheets. I need to list out tasks currently scheduled for a specific date but there is a volume cut off that needs to happen.

```
Client  Scheduled For   Volume
A       Mar-17          2000
B       Mar-17          1000
C       Mar-17          3000
D       Mar-17          500
E       Mar-17          250
F       Mar-17          1000
```

What I would like to do is list **Client's** until listing a new client would pass a limit of **6000**. So in the above example, the new data would look like:

```
Client  Scheduled For   Volume
A       Mar-17          2000
B       Mar-17          1000
C       Mar-17          3000
```

So far I have managed to select Clients by Date, but my research could not find a solution for the volume limit.

```
=QUERY(RawData!A2:C, "select A,B,C where B = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("3/17/2019"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

There are no preferences for how this gets done other than it has to be done in Google Sheets. `QUERY` is not required.

Comment: how many clients with same day could be there in real ?

Comment: Approximately 20

Comment: that should be doable... just extend the formula from the answer with 10 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- here is how you do it accounting for a maximum of 10 clients:

```
=QUERY(A30:C, "where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' limit "&IFS(
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 10"))<=6000,10,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 9"))<=6000,9,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 8"))<=6000,8,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 7"))<=6000,7,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 6"))<=6000,6,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 5"))<=6000,5,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 4"))<=6000,4,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 3"))<=6000,3,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 2"))<=6000,2,
 SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A30:C, "select C where B=date'"&TEXT(F29,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'limit 1"))<=6000,1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I noticed that Limit 9 is there twice. Not as a critique but in-case anyone else intends to use.Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @GregSmith fixed, thx